# Is there a guideline/best practices for creating monitors for a newly developed service?

Tags: monitoring, alarm, monitor

I have developed a new service that will be internally used within my company. I have a following questions around monitors

- How do I decide the threshold for the monitors (lets say number of errors in log files / 5 min)? Should it be 3% of the peak traffic or 3% of avg traffic?
- What if the traffic is in the form of sinusoidal wave. How do I made sure that I do not miss an issue during off peak hour and at the same time make sure that I do not get alarmed for false positives during peak hours.

I know this is a bit vague questions and the solution may vary from service to service. But I am more interested in the best practices that should be followed.

**PS**: we already have a monitoring system we are only trying to create alarms with the right threshold.

Answer (score 0):

I sense two questions from the above:

1. For a new service how do I select the right
   error/latency/availability threshold?
2. For a service getting
       traffic with a sinusoidal wave pattern, how can I adjust my
       thresholds to not miss error in low/high traffic situations?

Well, for the first, the ideal situation is that the latency and availability guarantees were part of your initial requirements. It is hard to accommodate an existing system to a threshold or SLA if your service wasn't designed for it. So, hopefully you either got those numbers as requirements (and incorporated into your design) or you had some goal in mind while designing the system. Otherwise your service can do no better than what it is doing at its best case. So select that one. Unless you have the option of re-architecting the system, in which case, back to square one.

For alerting on various traffic patterns, it depends on what tooling is available to you for monitoring and alerting. You mentioned that your company already has a dedicated monitoring system; there could be solutions that allow you to define rules while creating error and latency thresholds. Depending on the sophistication of these tools, these rules may even allow you to define thresholds relative to some other metric (like total traffic to your main product/website that this service is supporting). If such tooling is not available, it becomes hard but you could get some leverage out by depending on percentile metrics instead of absolute thresholds. Like error should be no more than .001%. If your monitoring system does not support such calculations, you can explore the excellent [metrics library written by Coda Hale](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/) to determine some of these percentiles in your service itself.